# Creating an comma-separated array in vb only shows last value of array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem and any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a comma-separated array I am using to obtain the selected value of a dropdown list. The problem is that that the array is only displaying the last value.

Here is my code:

```
Dim values As String
values = "RO,RW"

Dim sites As String() = Nothing
sites = values.Split(",")

Dim s As String

For Each s In sites
    emptytext.SelectedItem.Text = s
Next
```

Comment: What you trying to do here?? trying to setting up values based on split array?

Comment: You know that the array contains more than one value, right?  So which one do you want to select?

Comment: I have 2 dropdowns on a form and the values for these dropdowns are either RO or RW. In my vb I have the array of "RO,RW" I split this at the comma but only the last value is shown in the dropdownlist selected value. I want the first dropdown to have a selected value of RO and the second to have a selected value of RW.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the variable `s` always to the same item results in the behavior described.
Probably you want something like this (Supposing that emptyText is a combobox or listbox of sort)

```
 emptytext.Items.Clear()
 For Each s In sites
      emptytext.Items.Add(s)
 Next
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to use a `DatsSource` here? so can skip the looping if the array contains many items :)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty probably yes, I have focused my answer on the OP error.

Comment: I am trying to set the selectedvalue based on the split array. I would use a datasource but unfortunately this is not being saved toa database. Thanks for your answer I did try it out but now the array only shows the first value.

Comment: Can you explain what is emptyText? I assumed it to be a listbox or?

Comment: emptytext is the name of my dropdownlist

Comment: Cannot figure out why, try to use a debugger stepping through this code. It should add two different items to your DDL

Answer (score 1):

You commented that you have *two* dropdowns, and you want the values in the comma-separated list to be the selected items in the dropdowns. So you will need to go through the items *and* dropdowns in turn and set the selecteditem of each.

I made a Windows Forms project form looking like this:

[image: Unpopulated dropdowns]

(the controls all have their default names).

Then I used the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim ddls() As ComboBox

    Private Sub SetUpDropdowns()
        Dim values() As String = "RO,RW".Split(","c)
        ddls = {ComboBox1, ComboBox2}

        For Each ddl In ddls
            ddl.Items.AddRange(values)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim settings = TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)

        If settings.Count > ddls.Count Then
            MsgBox(String.Format("Too many setting values entered, maximum is {0}.", ddls.Count))
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For i = 0 To settings.Count - 1
            ddls(i).SelectedItem = settings(i)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetUpDropdowns()

    End Sub

End Class
```

[Edited: use .AddRange in the setup instead of .Add in a loop.]

I entered `RO,RW` in the TextBox and clicked Button1 to get this:

[image: Populated dropdowns]

Comment: Thank You Andrew this was exactly what I was looking for I will give this a try and let you know how it works out.